# Cannot edit data using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii framework. I am doing update operation in yii framework. I have controller with name *sitecontroller.php*, model *jobseekerprofile.php*, view *personal.php*. Firstly I want to select data and display it in textbox in form. I got an error message

```
Array to string conversion.
```

My controler page *sitecontroller.php* :

```
 <?php
    class SiteController extends Controller
      {
     public function actionpersonal()
      {
        $user_id = trim($_GET['id']);
        /*$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->compare('user_id', '97');
        $model = jobseekerprofile::model()->findAll($criteria);*/
        var_dump($user_id);
        $model=jobseekerprofile::model()->findAll(array(
                                             'select'=>'contact_no',"condition"=>"user_id=$user_id",
                                             'limit'=>1,));
        $this->render('personal',array('model' =>$model));
      }
       }
  ?>
```

View-*personal.php* :

```
    <div class="form">
      <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
        'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true
    ),
       )); ?>

      <?php
        foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
        echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
        }
       ?>
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
       <div class="row">
       <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'pp_status', array('value'=>'Open', 'readonly' => 'true')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Contact No'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'contact_no'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'contact_no'); ?>
    </div>
     <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
    </div>

   <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
   </div>
```

Anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `findAll()` returns array of models, to get one model you should use `find()` method

```
$model=jobseekerprofile::model()->find(array(
    'select'=>'contact_no',
    "condition"=>"user_id=$user_id",
));
```